# Skype API with Processing or Arduino

Tags: java, sdk, processing, arduino, skype

I want to write a [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) sketch to listen in on a local Skype call happening in the Skype desktop client. Skype offers a Desktop API as well as an SDK, but I don't know how to integrate these with Processing. I need to stick with Processing, because I am trying to control an Arduino board with an incoming Skype chat.

I know this is a reasonable ask, since the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library is a similar type of solution that works if I wanted to listen to a Twiiter feed. I think the trick is getting the Java version of the Skype SDK manipulated in such a way that it works as a library for Processing.

By "Processing", I mean the language, which you can find at [processing.org](http://processing.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would not to be to develop it as a Processing-specific library, but a Java one.

Processing can use the methods of any Java library anyway, like the Twitter4J library you mention.